# How to select dropdown menu item which is defined under <span> tag using Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table, automation

```html
<div class="span3">
                <div>
                    LSP Account<br>
                    <span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="cboAccountSettings_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="7245f0ab-5ba4-4c7b-b722-6c204d700e9f" style="width: 98%;">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Any</span>
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span></span></span>
                    
                    <select id="cboAccountSettings" style="width: 98%; display: none;" data-value-primitive="true" data-bind="value: SWO_Id" data-role="dropdownlist">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
                    <option value="SWO-ARG">SoftwareONE ARG</option>
                    <option value="SWO-AUS">SoftwareONE AUS</option>
                    <option value="SWO-BOL">SoftwareONE BOL</option>
                    <option value="SWO-BRA">SoftwareONE BRA</option>
                    <option value="SWO-CAN">SoftwareONE CAN</option>
                    <option value="SWO-CHL">SoftwareONE CHL</option>
                    <option value="SWO-COL">SoftwareONE COL</option>
                    <option value="SWO-CRI">SoftwareONE CRI</option>
                    <option value="SWO-DOM">SoftwareONE DOM</option>
                    <option value="SWO-ECU">SoftwareONE ECU</option>
                    <option value="SWO-EMEA">SoftwareONE EMEA</option>
                    <option value="SWO-GTM">SoftwareONE GTM</option>
                    <option value="SWO-HKG">SoftwareONE HKG</option>
                    <option value="SWO-HND">SoftwareONE HND</option>
                    <option value="SWO-IDN">SoftwareONE IDN</option>
                    <option value="SWO-JAM">SoftwareONE JAM</option>
                    <option value="SWO-JPN">SoftwareONE JPN</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

1) I was able to click on the  tag using, but not able to select the item:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[aria-owns='cboAccountSettings_listbox']")).Click();
```

2) I used this code also, but not able to find the specific element:

```
var LSPAccount = WebBrowser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[aria-owns='cboAccountSettings_listbox']"));   
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var selectElement = new SelectElement(LSPAccount);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
selectElement.SelectByValue("SWO-ARG");
```

3) I also tried this , but no success:

```
var xpath = "//span[contains(@class,'k-widget k-dropdown k-header')][contains(@id,'cboAccountSettings')][contains(text(),'SoftwareONE ARG')]";
var admi = WebBrowser.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
admi.Click();
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Is there a public link to this page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
//get the select html element
var selectList = driver.FindElement(By.Selector("select#cboAccountSettings"));
//wrap it inside webdriver's SelectElement and select option with value "SWO-ARG"
var selectElement = new SelectElement(selectList);
selectElement.SelectByValue("SWO-ARG");
```

SelectElement expects a IWebElement that represents a html select. Also, Please check that target select element is not inside some frame. In that case switch to target frame first.

Comment: Or, more simply: `var selectList = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cboAccountSettings"));`

Comment: Indeed !! However, i prefer using css selectors as i can specify element type as well along with id just in case there is some other element having same id. Otherwise, i will have to find all and use indexing or some other alternative to reach the target element !!

Comment: Not Helpful , as already mentioned - <select> item is inside <span> tag , so through this - you will not able to find the specific #Id.

Answer (score 0):

Select element is not visible that's the problem. You can use javascript to select option (Java):

```
String option = "SWO-ARG";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].selected='selected';", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cboAccountSettings option[value='" + option + "']")));
```

Try also this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('selected');", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cboAccountSettings option[selected]")));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cboAccountSettings option[value='SWO-ARG']")));
```

Comment: thanks for Answer, but it seems that - I can find the specific element by this code but the particular value is not selected in drop down.While Debugging - it is giving 'Null' in the variable. --Can you please review it

Comment: Share html as text

Comment: edit the Htm in Code, Hope you code read that- it is tough to copy paste - please refer screen shot also , while creating the environemnt with same code

Comment: Please select manual some value like "SoftwareONE ARG" then open developer tools and search for "SoftwareONE ARG", probably you will find div or ul/li with the value in html and share those html part. If can share url it will be much easy.